# chrome, android browser not rendering image styles

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, reactjs

I have a react component, that loads some data, iterates over an array and also inputs a bunch of images from lorempixel.

I have the following styles for these images:

```
.ekipa-list .ekipa-li .ekipa-li-headshot {
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

These get applied in one of my views correctly. They also get applied correctly in Safari and Firefox. But they do not get applied on initial load in another view. Both views are loading the same component with the same data.

However, I can see the styles in Chrome when inspecting the elements, but they are not rendered

To reproduce this go to:
http://altereko.si/#/zavod

See the images in the bottom list. Then go to kontakt, and see them render correctly. They will also render correctly upon screen resize.

This issue seems to be caused by this line of code:

```
{this.props.bio ? <p className="ekipa-li-bio">{this.props.bio}</p> :null}
```

When I remove it from my component:

```
render() {
    return (
      <li className="ekipa-li" id={this.props.id}>
        <div className="ekipa-li-visible" onClick={this.expandContact}>
          <img alt="portret-člana-ekipe" className="ekipa-li-headshot" src={this.props.photo}/>
          <div className="ekipa-li-text">
            <p className="ekipa-li-name">{this.props.name}</p>
            <p className="ekipa-li-function">{this.props.function}</p>
            {this.props.bio ? <p className="ekipa-li-bio">{this.props.bio}</p> :null}
          </div>
        </div>
        {!this.state.hidden
            ? (<div className="ekipa-li-expand">
              <div className="ekipa-li-expand-link-container">
                <a className="ekipa-li-expand-link" href={'mailto:'+this.props.email}>
                  <i className="ekipa-li-icon material-icons">email</i>
                  <span className="ekipa-li-expand-link-text">{this.props.email}</span>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="ekipa-li-expand-link-container">
                <a className="ekipa-li-expand-link" href={'tel:'+this.props.mobile}>
                  <i className="ekipa-li-icon material-icons">stay_current_portrait</i>
                  <span className="ekipa-li-expand-link-text">{this.props.mobile}</span>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>)
            : null}
      </li>
    )
  }
```

Everything renders as expected.

Same thing happens when I do not pass the bio prop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest fix is to wrap your `img` into a `div`. Currently this is happening because `zavod` page has multiline paragraph text that is wrapping and stretching the flex layout.

```css
.flex {
  display:flex;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <img alt="portret-člana-ekipe" class="ekipa-li-headshot" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
  <div>
    <p>
      Nam erat mi, ullamcorper at blandit in, lacinia at magna. Suspendisse sit amet dapibus justo. Nam finibus nibh at viverra vehicula. Mauris posuere ac dui nec sollicitudin. Sed varius sed justo in elementum. Aliquam euismod nisl et massa fermentum tempus. Suspendisse et efficitur metus. Donec eleifend mi consequat libero semper mattis.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flex">
  <div>
    <img alt="portret-člana-ekipe" class="ekipa-li-headshot" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      Nam erat mi, ullamcorper at blandit in, lacinia at magna. Suspendisse sit amet dapibus justo. Nam finibus nibh at viverra vehicula. Mauris posuere ac dui nec sollicitudin. Sed varius sed justo in elementum. Aliquam euismod nisl et massa fermentum tempus. Suspendisse et efficitur metus. Donec eleifend mi consequat libero semper mattis.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still weird that firefox and safari rendered this as expected...Thanks for the help